# How to use EJBContext in JUnit?

Tags: java, junit, ejb

I am accessing context using below annotation in my `JUnit`.

```
@Resource
private EJBContext context;
```

And in my `JUnit` Test Case, I am accessing it like :-

```
context.setRollbackOnly();
```

Issue :- context is coming `null` at run time (`NullPointerException`).

Requirement :-

1. How to use context in `JUnit` ?
2. I want to roll back the changes if my `JUnit` fails. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Which test runner are you using?

Comment: I am not using or implemented any test runner in my JUnit.

Comment: Then the @Resource annotation is useless. You need to run the test in a container to get something injected (Arquillian tests would help). Better grab mockito and mock the context.